Firefox Ubuntu 22.04 font hinting problem
I don't like font antialiasing and always turn it off. Previously I used Ubuntu 14.04, now I'm switching to 22.04. For most applications I have disabled antialiasing using gnome-tweaks, in both systems. Firefox required special measures. Under 14.04, I solved the problem by setting autohinting=false, hinting=true, hintstyle=hintfull, antialias=false in ~/.fonts.conf. The result satisfied me, see enlarged image below.

At 22.04 this solution does not work. I used this advice:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357140/disable-anti-aliasing-in-google-chrome-or-firefox

in firefox, go to about:config, change gfx.text.disable-aa to true.

Now antialiasing is disabled, but the fonts look terrible, see the image below.

I suspect this is due to the different hinting configuration, but I can't find a way to change it.
Please help!
